# Django/Python: {% syntax not working.

Tags: python, django

I am new to django (learning on django 1.8) and am doing this tutorial
https://django-by-errors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

This is how the model looks like.

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(viewname="food-detail", args=[self.id])

    def get_list_url(self):
        return reverse(viewname="food-list")
```

This is how my url patterns looks like

```
urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.current_datetime),
    #url(r'^food/$', food_list, name='food-list'),
    url(r'^food/$', FoodListView.as_view(), name='food-list'),
    url(r'^food/(?P<pk>\d+)$', FoodDetailView.as_view(), name='food-detail'),
]
```

Now, in template file (food_detail.html), following syntax works

```
<p><a href="{{ object.get_list_url }}">Back to food list</a></p>
```

but this syntax doesn't work

```
p><a href="{% url food-list %}">Back to food list</a></p>
```

It throws the error 
**Could not parse the remainder: '-list' from 'food-list'**

I am wondering why this error occurs. Please help! I am using django 1.8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right syntax would be `{% url 'food-list' %}`

You need to change your link in the template to:

`<p><a href="{% url 'food-list' %}">Back to food list</a></p>`